# How can I add custom field to order by on the admin CP in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to add a custom field for order by on the drop down menu on admin CP. How can I do it, is there any event for this in Craft 3?

It is a plugin related question, we are using custom plugin to customize our application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this question [Set custom sort order for index pages in the CP?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/set-custom-sort-order-for-index-pages-in-the-cp) for Craft 2 and see [updating Plugins for Craft 3](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/updating-plugins.html#modifyentrysortableattributes-modifycategorysortableattributes-modifyassetsortableattributes-modifyusersortableattributes) in the docs

```php
// Old:
public function modifyEntrySortableAttributes(&$attributes)
{
    $attributes['id'] = Craft::t('ID');
}

// New:
use craft\base\Element;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\RegisterElementSortOptionsEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SORT_OPTIONS, function(RegisterElementSortOptionsEvent $event) {
    $event->sortOptions['id'] = \Craft::t('app', 'ID');
});
```

Keep in mind your field must be sortable via SQL

Comment: In this way, this **sort option type** will be applied to all the sections. What if some of the sections don't have this **sort option type**?

Comment: @yuxia `$event->sender` contains the element so you can check it's section and entry type

Comment: Unfortunately, for me it's not working. I dd out the **$event**:
`
RegisterElementSortOptionsEvent {#4331 ▼
  +sortOptions: array:8 [▶]
  +name: "registerSortOptions"
  +sender: null
  +handled: false
  +data: null
}
`